Troubleshooting Iterator-Like Concept Definition for Pointer-Like Iterators in C++
I am new in C++20. I’ve been refining a C++ concept, IteratorLike, designed to encapsulate the behavior of iterators. The concept checks for element access, iterator advancement, and end-of-sequence comparison. Here’s the concept definition:
template <typename Iter, typename ValueType, typename AccessFn, typename NextFn>
concept IteratorLike = std::invocable<AccessFn, Iter>
    && std::invocable<NextFn, Iter>
    && std::equality_comparable<Iter>
    && std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<std::invoke_result_t<AccessFn, Iter>>, ValueType>
    && std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<std::invoke_result_t<NextFn, Iter>>, Iter>;

But I’m not sure how to apply the definition of an iterator with pointer semantics to this concept, or perhaps there might be shortcomings in my definition of the IteratorLike concept.
I would appreciate any suggestions for improvement.

The use of decltype with the overloaded operators is causing a compilation error:
static_assert(
    IteratorLike<
        std::vector<int>::iterator,
        int,
        decltype(&std::vector<int>::iterator::operator*),
        decltype(&std::vector<int>::iterator::operator++)
    >
);

The compiler returns: ‘error: ‘decltype’ cannot resolve address of overloaded function.’

related


‘error: ‘decltype’ cannot resolve address of overloaded function.’

There are two operator++ overloads. One for pre-increment (++it) and one for post-increment (it++). When you take the address of std::vector<int>::iterator::operator++ the compiler has no idea which one you want so you need to help it.
Example:
// taking the address of the pre-increment operator++
std::vector<int>::iterator& (std::vector<int>::iterator::*preinc)() =
    &std::vector<int>::iterator::operator++;

// taking the address of the post-increment operator++
std::vector<int>::iterator (std::vector<int>::iterator::*postinc)(int) =
    &std::vector<int>::iterator::operator++;

static_assert(IteratorLike<std::vector<int>::iterator, int,
                           decltype(&std::vector<int>::iterator::operator*),
                           decltype(preinc)>);

Note though that not all iterators are of class type. A std::vector<T>::iterator may just be a plain pointer, and if so, you can't take the address of its operator* or any of operator++.

Thank you for your reply, it was very helpful. Based on your response, I’ve defined the following:
template<typename It> It &(It::*preinc)() = &It::operator++; template<typename It, typename ValueType> It (It::*postinc)(ValueType) = &It::operator++;
It works fine.
however, my main concern is whether there’s an issue with the IteratorLike definition, or if there’s a better way to define this concept?

@燈火ヤ Yeah, the issue I think of is the one I mentioned in the answer. If the iterator type is nothing more than a plain pointer.  The concept will reject it.


I am new in C++20. I’ve been refining a C++ concept, IteratorLike,
designed to encapsulate the behavior of iterators.

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. There are corresponding concepts in <iterator>.
The std::input_or_output_iterator concept defines the requirements for iterator-like types, including support for dereference, increment operations, etc.
The std::sentinel_for concept defines requirements for sentinel-like types, which can be compared to iterator types to indicate the end of the range.
The std::forward_iterator refines input_or_output_iterator to support multi-pass and ensure that different two can be compared, which corresponds to the equality_comparable part in your concept.

Thank you for your response.
I’ve looked briefly at the definitions of std::input_or_output_iterator and std::sentinel_for, but I don’t think they are what I’m looking for.
I’m seeking a more general concept, one that can describe any iterator duck typing.

For example, consider this not entirely appropriate example:
struct ListNode  { int val; ListNode *next; ListNode(int x = 0, ListNode *p = nullptr) : val(x), next(nullptr){}; };
static_assert(IteratorLike<     ListNode*,      ListNode,      decltype([](ListNode* p) { return *p; }),      decltype([](ListNode* p) { return p->next; })> );
Here, ListNode* is not a typical pointer semantic iterator, but it exhibits iterator behavior.
I feel that std::input_or_output_iterator and std::sentinel_for do not meet this requirement.

@燈火ヤ Any pointer satisfies input_or_output_iterator.
